# The action in addTarget of my button does not work

Tags: swift

Xcode did not report errors but nothing was printed when I pressed the button.
I tried it with action:

```
#selector (print), action: #selector (self.print), action: #selector (ViewController.print)..etc..
```

Swift 4, Xcode 10.1

```
class SomeViewController:UIViewController {
var button:UIButton = UIButton()
func setupButton()
{
    button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 140, y: 140, width: 90, height: 40))
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(print(-:)) , for: .touchUpOutside)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(button)
    button.setTitle("Convert", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .yellow
    view.addSubview(button)


}

@objc func print(_sender: UIButton)
{
    print("Stackoverflow")
}

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(CollectionView)
    CollectionView.frame = view.frame
    setupButton()
 }
}
```

Comment: just change the function name (print1 for axample!)
and selector need only the name of the function
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(print1) , for: .touchUpOutside)

Answer (score 0):

Change this ( You need `touchUpInside` instead of `touchUpOutside` )

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(print(_:)) , for: .touchUpOutside)
```

to

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(printRes) , for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func printRes(_ sender: UIButton) { }
```

Also don't use `print` as button action name because it's a reserved method

---

Also to get the button click action set it's type

```
button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.frame  = CGRect(x: 140, y: 140, width: 90, height: 40)
```

Comment: I change my code with "touchUpInside" and "button.frame" and it's very good.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change event type from .touchUpOutside to .touchUpInside

Here is [events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event) documentation

Comment: Thank you, exactly!